# Integration of meteor application

Tags: meteor

I have a application in which there are several templates. I am calling these templates into one single page application by using the function ,

```
$('#right2').replaceWith(Meteor.ui.chunk(Template.profile));
```

where `"'#right2'"` is the id of the div to be replaced. & the `"Template.Profile"` is the replacing template.

What happens is that,

when I call all those templates on the click of a hyperlink, they get called only once.. When I call those templates once again, it doesn't work.

`<li><a href="#" onclick = "renderMessage_Inbox();" ></a></li>`

```
function renderMessage_Inbox(){       
alert("in messages");
$('#right2').replaceWith(Meteor.ui.chunk(Template.Message_Inbox));
```

}

The template:

```
<template name = "Message_Inbox">
<div id="right2">

<div class="floatLeft">
 <a href="Messages_Inbox.html"> <img src="/messagesText.png" alt="messages" class="floatLeft" /></a><span class="new floatLeft">1 NEW </span>
 </div> 

  <div align="center" class="floatRight" style="margin-bottom:20px">

<a href="#" class="button" onclick="ShowModalPopup('popupMessage'); return false;">
    <span>+ New Message</span>
</a>
</div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <div class="count" style="margin-bottom:10px"> 4 Messages</div>

  <!--start 1 messageBox-->
  <a href="#" onclick = "renderInbox_Details();" class="messageBox">
  <div class="left">

    <img src="/photo.jpg" style="margin-right:10px" class="floatLeft" />
    <p class="">Bill Brady</p>

    <p class="messageTitle" style="clear:none;">Title of the message</p>
    </div>

    <div class="floatRight">
     <p class="" align="right">X</p>

    <p class="messageTitle">March 12, 2012</p>

    </div>

   </a>
 </div> 

</template>
```

I have several such calling functions & templates. But they get called only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $('#right2').html(Meteor.ui.chunk(Template.Message_Inbox));

It will solve your problem.